# Do sqlite add column have space requirement?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have an iOS app which uses sqlite as database. When the app updates its database, some users says that their data losts after update.

According to user log(which is incomplete), the disk space is zero. I cannot get the log about the alter table SQL statment. But I am sure the data is lost.

SQL statment is `alter table songs add column int34 integer not null default 0`

I think `add column` is implemented like this

1. create new table
2. copy data from old table to new table
3. drop old table
4. rename new table

If there is no space, an error may occur when copying data from old table to new table. Am i right? Is there offical statment about that？ I google a lot, but find nothing.

Now I know I need to handle sqlite errors when updating database(I mean when `add column`).
When the disk is full, I think the database remains the same after executing `add column`. But I find that (according to user log) there is a new table with added columns and zero recored which means user lost there data!

Why does this happen?
Code to update sqlite as follows    :

```
       //I am sure the database file exists
       sqlite3_open_v2([pathForSqlite UTF8String], &DB, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE|SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE|SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX,NULL);

       //I am Sure the  SONGS table exists
       NSString *sql = @"alter table SONGS add column int23 integer not null default 0";

       sqlite3_exec(DB, sql.UTF8String, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

CL. is right. I simulated the situation which turns out that the DB remains in old state.
Code as follows

```
+ (void)wirteBigFile
{

unsigned long long totalSpace = 0;
unsigned long long totalFreeSpace = 0;
do
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];
    BOOL ret = YES;
    if (dictionary) {
        NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];
        NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
        totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu MiB with %llu MiB Free memory available.", ((totalSpace/1024ll)/1024ll), ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll));

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@, Code = %ld", [error domain], (long)[error code]);
        return;
    }


    long long int size = totalFreeSpace/2;



    FILE *file;
    NSString *dateString = [[[NSDate date] description ] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSArray *timeArray =[dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    dateString = [timeArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fd%@",dateString];
    dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
    dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Documents/%@.ttt",dateString];
    NSString *fPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

    file = fopen([fPath UTF8String], "wb+");

    fsetpos(file, &size);

    fwrite("", 1, 1, file);

    fclose(file);
    paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    if (totalFreeSpace < 20000000)
    {
        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alter table SONGS add column %@ integer not null default 0",dateString];
        int retd = [[QQMusicDBAdapter sharedQQMusicDBAdapter] executeSQL:sql];
        if (retd != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];
    if (dictionary) {
        NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];
        NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
        totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu MiB with %llu MiB Free memory available.", ((totalSpace/1024ll)/1024ll), ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll));

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@, Code = %ld", [error domain], (long)[error code]);
        return;
    }
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];

}
while (1);

NSLog(@"error");
}
```

I still have no idea why user data is lost.

Comment: `add column` is not implemented like that, and in any case, *all* changes are fully transactional. Your error handling is wrong.

Comment: Then is it possible `add column` fail because of no space？what's the consequence of `add column` incase of no space?

Comment: Just like with any other error; the `sqlite3_*` functions will return some error code.

Comment: would the records in database lost?

Comment: No; if a transaction fails, the DB stays in the old state.

Comment: Can I get some document or guidelines about the situation(alter table when no space)